# rolling deployment for docker containers behind load balancer

Tags: deployment, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with rolling deployments of docker containers behind a load balancer.

Here is my docker compose yml file contents.

```
nginx:
    image: nginx_image
    links:
        - node1:node1
        - node2:node2
        - node3:node3
    ports:
        - "80:80"
node1:
    image: nodeapi_image
    ports:
        - "8001"
node2:
    image: nodeapi_image
    ports:
        - "8001"
node3:
    image: nodeapi_image
    ports:
        - "8001"
```

and here my `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  upstream node-app {
        least_conn;
        server node1:8001 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server node2:8001 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server node3:8001 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  }

  server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        # ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/imago.io.chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/imago.io.key;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://node-app;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
  }
}
```

If I have a new built image I want to deploy I have to stop a node container, remove it and recreate it with the new image. The problem here is that the new container will get a new IP and the nginx container doesnt know about that new IP, so if I recreate the 3 containers behind the load balancer once I recreate the last one the app wont serve any more because all IPs in the nginx machines `/etc/hosts` and environment vairables are not up to date any more.

I could SSH in to each container, update its code by pulling from the git repo and restart the process but that seems just wrong to me. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I had a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44960088/2112538 Do you have an idea on how to handle this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way to achieve this, take the following *docker-compose.yml* file as an example :

```yaml
lb:
    image: tutum/haproxy
    links:
        - app
    ports:
        - "80:80"
app:
    image: tutum/hello-world
```

This docker compose file describes two services :

- lb: a load balancer which uses the [tutum/haproxy](https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy) image
- app: a sample webapp listening on port 80

If you start those services naïvely with `docker-compose up -d`, you will end up with only 2 containers (the load balancer and the web app).

But if you run `docker-compose scale app=3` then run again `docker-compose up -d`, you will end up with 4 load-balanced containers.

The key player here is the `tutum/haproxy` docker image which is able to discover the different containers it is linked to.

---

A similar solution is to use [Jason Wilder's nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) image which has the advantage of discovering the new nodes live ; so you won't have to restart the `lb` service.

```
lb:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
        - "80:80"
app:
    image: tutum/hello-world
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: www.mysite.com
```

The `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable must be set to the domain name that resolves to the IP address of your docker host.

---

Another one is to use [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/)

```
lb:
  image: traefik
  command: --docker
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

app:
  image: tutum/hello-world
  labels:
    traefik.frontend.rule: Host:www.mysite.com
```

The `traefik.frontend.rule` label must define a [Traefik rule](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers) set to the domain name that resolves to the IP address of your docker host.

Traefik also offers different [load balancing strategies](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#load-balancing) and [circuit breakers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#circuit-breakers).

Comment: ok i see. while i like your answer it seems like the tutum/haproxy container would work only if you use tutum. the other approach looks nice and i will give it a shot. in the meantime i wrote some code that does the trick by updating the /etc/hosts on the loadbalancer and reloads nginx or haproxy once done.

Comment: the tutum/haproxy works everywhere. The difference is that it will update live only if hosted on tutum hosting service.

Comment: you just run `docker-compose up -d lb` and the load balancer container will be recreated and will notice the new app containers

Comment: ok but that defeats the purpose of having a running deployment without downtime. it basically equals to kill everything and recreate it.

Comment: yes it does, short downtime, but still a downtime. If you use the solution with `jwilder/nginx-proxy`, there is no downtime

Comment: while i created a script to make this happen i accepted the answer. i am using joyent triton and i have to check if the nginx-proxy approach would work there. thx

Comment: Both of these solutions require that all nodes and LB run on the same host.

Comment: @allingeek not anymore, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/ which is available since Docker 1.9