# With jwilder nginx-proxy, how to proxypass a subdirectory url to a specific container?

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) to make a reverse proxy. I try to redirect `http://localhost:8000/api` to a specific php service.

The directory structure:

```
.
+-- docker-compose.yml
+-- nginx
+-- nodejs
|   +-- index.js
|   +-- …
+-- php
|   +-- api
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./php:/srv/www
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nodejs:
    image: node:alpine
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
    expose:
      - "8080"
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/home/app
    command: ["node", "index.js"]

  php:
    image: php:apache
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html
```

This works fine for the `nodejs` service.

**Now, I would like to redirect calls to `http://localhost:8000/api` to the `php` service.** I imagine that I have to add to the `nginx conf` something like:

```
server {
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://php:80/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

[This feature is not built into the lib](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/635).
So, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to give the php app its own virtual host:

```
  php:
    image: php:apache
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.localhost
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html
```

Then, it will be accesible as this:

```
curl -H 'Host: api.localhost' http://localhost:8000/api
```

Setting the header can be achieved in practically any language. Or to avoid setting custom header, you can add that DNS to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 api.localhost
```

So you can curl as this:

```
curl -H http://api.localhost:8000/api
```

This is how set custom headers, for example in node:

```
var request = require('request')

var formData = {}

request({
    headers: {
      'Host': 'api.localhost'
    },
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
      console.log("it works")
      console.log(res)
    }
)
```

But, I recommend you to go for the /etc/hosts approach, that should has an equivalent in production environment (a DNS server). So you don't need to touch node code.

Comment: Could you show an example on how / where I could set the custom header, please?

Comment: Thanks. Modifying DNS removes the portable logic of Docker. Modifying headers in every requests is not light either. Eventually, jwilder/nginx-proxy really complicate stuffs compared to the simple nginx config in my previous question… I have to think about it

Comment: Does it make sense to modify the `/etc/hosts` file inside the nginx container?

Comment: No, I doesn't. Nginx contact each container by their IPS.   But, to access php api from node just do this: `http://php/api`, there is no need to pass through nginx if php doesn't scale